# system() and CreateProcess() / CreateProcessW()

Tags: windows, system, createprocess, external-process

I want to execute a TEST.exe in a C program. While I use

```
system( "TEST.exe <input-file> output-file" );
```

I can get what I expected.

But CreateProcessW() didn't work properly when I use the following code (see [How do I run an external program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550488/how-do-i-run-an-external-program)):

```
if (CreateProcessW(const_cast<LPCWSTR>(FullPathToExe.c_str()), 
    pwszParam, 0, 0, false, 
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0, 
    &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) != false) 
{ 
    /* Watch the process. */ 
    dwExitCode = WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess,  (SecondsToWait * 1000)); 
    iReturnVal = GetLastError(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    /* CreateProcess failed */ 
    iReturnVal = GetLastError(); 
}
```

where

```
FullPathToExe="TEST.exe", pwszParam="TEST.exe <input-file> output-file".
```

And WaitForSingleObject() returns 258, GetLastError() returns 1813 ("The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.").

Also, The above CreateProcessW() code works fine when I run my own HelloProcess.exe (print hello, and sleep some seconds determined by the following number, then exit.) with

```
FullPathToExe="HelloProcess.exe", pwszParam="HelloProcess.exe 10".
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Is FullPathToExe a string or a wstring?

Comment: It's a wstring. I think the types of variables are OK, since the code runs well with my own *.exe.

I wonder if there is some problem with the "<"/">" in the parameters?

Comment: Title should be changed to “Input/output redirection: system() vs. CreateProcess()” but I’m not allowed to edit it. Also spacing is inconsequential – and hence misleading – in `<input-file> output-file`. Characters `<>` are prefixes but OP’s spacing implies they are parentheses. Spacing that wouldn’t be misleading: `<output-file >input-file`.

Answer (score 6):

`system` actually spawns a `cmd` instance in which your command is run:

> The **system** function passes command to the command interpreter, which executes the string as an operating-system command. **system** refers to the **COMSPEC** and **PATH** environment variables that locate the command-interpreter file (the file named CMD.EXE in Windows NT). If *command* is NULL, the function simply checks to see whether the command interpreter exists.
>   —[Documentation of `system`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx)

This is why redirection operators such as `<` and `>` work. This is not the case for `CreateProcess` which really just spawns a process instead of a shell that executes another process. Since the redirection operators are a feature of the shell and not the OS you'd have to do input and output to the process manually.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. And I find the solution to my problem now, hooray!!

Answer (score 3):

I do what [CreateProcess and command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649212/createprocess-and-command-line-arguments)
tells me to do, and fix the problem! Thank you guys for your attention!

For your convenience, here is the quotation of the answer:

> You cannot use command-line redirection operators with CreateProcess()
>   directly. You have to spawn an instance of cmd.exe and pass the
>   operators to it instead, eg:
>
> ```
> CreateProcess( "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", t_str2, ...))
> ```
>
> Where
>   t_str2 is "/C C:\Temp\sift.exe < C:\img1.pgm > C:\img1.key". The
>   actual path to cmd.exe can be determined by reading the %COMSPEC%
>   environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

WaitForSingleObject() returns a wait result, and not the exit code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx

258 is a WAIT_TIMEOUT. You should retry on this error code until you get the return value of 0 (WAIT_OBJECT_0), or some other error.

After this, use GetExitCodeProcess https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx 
to get the exit code of the process.